# Русский язык Словообразовательная цепочка

Tags: словообразование

**Это задание, которое было дано. Внизу мой ответ, помогите, пожалуйста.**

**Запишите слова в виде словообразовательной цепочки (словообразовательных цепочек).**

Ум, поумнеть, умный, умник, умнеть.

Правильно ли я составила: Ум -> умный -> умник -> умнеть -> поумнеть

Comment: Я бы и "умника', и "умнеть/поумнеть" производил от "умного"

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Ум —> умный —> умник;
умный —> умнеть —> поумнеть.

Вы совершенно верно составили словообразовательную цепочку, только учтите, что *умнеть* также, как и *умник*, образовано от прилагательного. В схеме они представляются как бы параллельными производными.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84973/discussion-on-answer-by-aer----).